# How do you change pitch with wavelet transforms in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, audio, wavelet

I'm trying to increase the pitch of a wav file using MATLAB. (I don't expect it to sound very good, but I'm trying to figure out how wavelets in MATLAB work.) Here's what I'm doing:

```
scales = {2.34375,0.5,21};
result = cwtft(b5,'scales',scales);
result.scales = 2*scales;
b5high = icwtft(result);
```

(`b5` is just the opening of Beethoven's Fifth, but it could be any sound file. It happens to have a sample rate of 48 kHz.)

To my thinking, I'm doing a wavelet transform of `b5` using a Morlet wavelet. The scales that I'm using capture the human-audible frequencies for a 48-kHz signal. I then double the scales vector--resulting in a shift upward of 1 octave, and then convert back into a signal. However, when I play `b5high`, it sounds exactly like `b5` - no pitch shifting at all.

What's wrong with my logic?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't implemented a pitch shifter using wavelets, but I am currently learning about them. From what I understand scales are the inverse of frequency, therefore to get your desired result you'd have to divide the scales instead of multiplying.

Furthermore, according to '[Applications of the Continuous Wavelet Transform in the Processing of Musical Signals](ftp://ftp.esat.kuleuven.ac.be/sista/degersem/reports/report97-17.ps.gz)', you also have to update the phase as adjusting the scales isn't enough. The algorithm outlined in the paper is:

```
semitone = 12;
pitchFactor = 2^(semitone/12);

wt = cwtft(input);

mag = abs(wt.cfs);
phase = angle(wt.cfs);
unwrapped = unwrap(phase);

wt.cfs = mag.*exp(1i*unwrapped*pitchFactor);
wt.scales = wt.scales./pitchFactor;

result = icwtft(wt);
```

Sadly, that's all I can offer until I learn more.

Comment: Whoever negative voted, can you explain why.

Comment: That helps a bit—thanks—but if I'd flipped the meaning of `scales`, I should still hear a _lowering_ of pitch, which I don't. There's still something wrong with my logic, that I'm trying to understand.